# What is the story of Goddess Shitala?

Tags: durga, goddess

What is the story of Goddess Shitala?

She is mainly worshiped in North India, West Bengal, Nepal, Bangladesh and Pakistan.

Comment: @EshanSingh Sheetala and Shitala both are right spelling but Shitla doesn't. Kindly submit edit with bit research.

Comment: @AnkitSharma i'm sry it's was my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Shitala literally means cool. It is believed that the Goddess provides coolness to Her devotees who are suffering from diseases.

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hmvp/hmvp47.htm) is something from Hindu Mythology

> *Shitala is the Bengali name for the small-pox, and for the deity who is supposed to have charge of that disease. The meaning of the word is
>   "She who makes cold." This goddess is represented as a
>   golden-complexioned woman sitting on a lotus, or riding on an ass,
>   dressed in red clothes. Before an image of this kind, or morecommonly
>   a pan of water merely, Shitala is worshipped in the hope that she will
>   preserve her worshippers from this dire disease. In the spring of the
>   year, the Hindus formerly inoculated their children for this disease
>   when they were about two years of age. The Brāhman who performed the
>   operation made presents to render Shitala propitious, and promised, in
>   case the work was successful, to give still greater gifts. At the
>   close of the operation the flowers that were presented to the goddess
>   were placed in the hair of the child as a charm. On behalf of those
>   afflicted with small-pox, offerings are made daily; and when the
>   patient is thought to be dangerously ill, he is placed in front of an
>   image of Shitala, bathed in, and given to drink, water that has been
>   offered to her. Beggars go about with a stone, partly gilded, which
>   they teach is sacred to Shitala, and, in seasons when the disease is
>   prevalent, receive presents from the superstitious.*

Here is an Another Source To Know More About Mata Shitla [OMASHRAM](http://www.omashram.com/news/78-the-day-of-shitala-devi)