# What's the story involving Shitala Devi & Jwarasura where Lord Vishnu gets inflicted by fever?

Tags: scripture, parvati, trinity, disease

As per Wikipedia

> *[Jvarasura or Jwarasura](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvarasura)* (ज्वरासुर) in Hindu mythology is the fever-deity and **consort of pox-deity goddess, *Shitala/Sheetala* (शीतला or *śītalā*).**

Further,

> **Once *Vishnu* was inflicted with fever of *Javarasura*,** when in form of
> **Haya-griva. He killed the fever-demon, *Jvarasura*,** by cutting him into
> three pieces using his cosmic-disk weapon, the *Sudarshana Chakra*.
> However, *Jvarasura* was later revived by *Brahma*, who joined the three
> parts.

The article on *[Shitala Deví](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shitala)*, citing *Skanda Purana*, mention something a bit different

> from Lord *Shiva's* sweat was born Jwarasura, who spread disease all
> over the world. Goddess *Shitala* rid the world from the disease, and
> **from then onwards, *Jvarasura* became her servant**.

So, at one point it's saying that *Jvarasura* is the consort of *Deví Sheetala* but then, it says he became her servant. Also, an *Asura* (even though born of *Shiva's* sweat) being a *Devi's* consort, dosen't add up. I'd like to get some explanation on this apparent paradox.

Also, what's the story of *Shri Vishnu* in his *Hayagreeva* form getting fever-afflicted? And exactly how or why (considering he's a God)?

**So, basically, I'd like to know all related stories (from different scriptures, if possible) in reference to *Deví Shitala* & *Jvarasura*, vis-a-vis, their connections with Lord *Shiva*, *Maa Parvatí*, Lord *Vishnu* & Lord *Brahmã*.**

---

Slightly Related Question: [What is the story of Goddess Shitala?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/what-is-the-story-of-goddess-shitala)

But, it doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: In Skanda Purana, Shitala is who cures children from diseases. Jvarasura's story is just a folklore.